# Как найти вложенные элементы?

Tags: jquery

Как найти вложенные элементы?

Вот так в JS мы можем найти вложенные элементы `table`:

```
  <div class="content">
     <div class="qtext"></div>
     <div class="еее">
        <div class="еее">
             <table class="answer"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
var $qtext = document.body.getElementsByClassName('qtext');
$table = $qtext[0].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

Вопрос: А как подобным образом мы можем найти в Jquery?

Я пытаюсь так, но не получается:

```
var $qtext2 = $('.qtext');
$qtext2.eq(0).parent().children('table').eq(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) смотрит на всю глубину, а метод [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) только непосредственных детей.

Если использовать метод [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) - то результат будет аналогичным.

Кроме того, не обязательно писать `eq(0)` в большинстве случаев их можно опустить.